# For loop takes forever to run

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, rstudio

I have two tables. One has info from 2012 till 2014 with the period of 3 hours. It looks like this:

```
                    B   C
1   01.06.2012 00:00    10  0   
2   01.06.2012 03:00    10  0   
3   01.06.2012 06:00    10  6   
4   01.06.2012 09:00    7,5 0   
5   01.06.2012 12:00    6   2,5 
6   01.06.2012 15:00    6   0   
7   01.06.2012 18:00    4   0   
8   01.06.2012 21:00    4   0   
9   02.06.2012 00:00    0   0   
10  02.06.2012 03:00    0   0
```

The other table is the same time but sampled by 1 minute:

```
1   01.06.2012 00:00       
2   01.06.2012 00:01       
3   01.06.2012 00:01       
4   01.06.2012 00:03       
5   01.06.2012 00:03       
6   01.06.2012 00:05       
7   01.06.2012 00:05       
8   01.06.2012 00:07       
9   01.06.2012 00:08       
10  01.06.2012 00:09       
11  01.06.2012 00:10
```

Now, I need the values of 2nd and 3rd rows of the second table to correlate to the first, so that if a timestamp from the second table is between `timestamp(i)` and `timestamp(i+1)` of the first table it will take the `B(i)` and `C(i)` and copy them. I have this code and I know it works, but it takes more than 12 hours to run it and I have many of such files that I need to work with in the same fashion.

```
clouds <- read.csv('~/2012-2014 clouds info.csv', sep=";", header = FALSE)
cloudFull <- read.csv('~/2012-2014 clouds.csv', sep=";", header = FALSE)

for (i in 1:nrow(cloudFull)){
  dateOne <- strptime(cloudFull[i,1], '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')

  for (j in 1:nrow(clouds)){
    bottomDate = strptime(clouds[j,1], '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
    upperDate = strptime(clouds[j+1,1], '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
    if  ((dateOne >= bottomDate) && (dateOne < upperDate)) {
      cloudFull[i,2] <- clouds[j,2]
      cloudFull[i,3] <- clouds[j,3]
      break

    } 

  }
}

write.csv(cloudFull, file = 'cc.csv')
```

Now how do I make it run faster? The `object.size(cloudFull)` gives me `39580744` bytes, it has `470000` rows but other files will have even more data. I'm just beginning with R (have worked in it for 2 days only so far) and I'd be grateful for any advice in a very simple language :D

Comment: You are comparing every row in `cloudfull` against every row in `cloud`. If both have 470000 entries than that is 470000*470000 compares, which is a lot. Assuming that both input files are sorted in date-time order then do some research on "merging" two files.

Comment: AdrianHHH is right, it is not R specific, it is about general algorithms. Use some kind of index to reduce search times. Do not use a for loop, you are using an algorithm which is of the order of o(n^2) in terms of complexity. A sorted table should bring this to o(n log(n)) and if you can afford it, just make a straight array (since your data is equally spaced without holes) to make it o(n)

Comment: cloud is sampled by 3 hours whereas cloudFull is sampled by 1 min which would mean that cloud is 180 times smaller.  but i'll look into "merging", thanks!

Comment: Use package data.table and do a rolling join. (Also, you are calling `strptime` for single values inside the loops. You could do that with the whole vectors outside the loops. In fact, the inner loop is not necessary if you use vectorization.)

Comment: hoist vectorizable operations outside of for loops, for instance `dateOne <- strptime(cloudFull[,1], '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')` outside the loop, `dateOne[i]` inside; likewise for the other `strptime()` invocations. `findInterval()` is an efficient way to place the fine-grained data into (sorted) bins; it might take some finesse to work with times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its hard to know what your real data looks like, but along the lines of

```
full <- strptime(cloudFull[,1], '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
ref <- strptime(clouds[,1], '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
## ref <- sort(ref)
cloudsFull[, 2:3] <- clouds[findInterval(full, ref), 2:3]
```

Use of `findInterval()` changes the problem into one that scales linearly rather than quadratic.